# How to change the text color of mx togglebuttonbar on mouseover

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I want to change the text color of the MX ToggleButtonBar control on rollover by changing the style i want to change the text color to different. can any one please help me.
For example i mouse overed on Home Button the text of the color should change to green but not background color.

```
<mx:ToggleButtonBar id="toggBar" direction="horizontal" horizontalGap="20" height="100" paddingLeft="60" 
                         horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" selectedIndex="1" 
                         >
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <fx:Object label="Home" id="home"  screenIndex="-1"/>
            <fx:Object label="About" id="about"  screenIndex="1"/>
            <fx:Object label="Contact" id="contact" screenIndex="2"/>
            <fx:Object label="Help" id="help" screenIndex="3"/>
        </mx:dataProvider> 
    </mx:ToggleButtonBar>
```

Comment: missing a space after id="contact"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mxml hack ( or comment in code ):

```
    <mx:ToggleButtonBar id="toggBar" direction="horizontal" horizontalGap="20" height="100" paddingLeft="60"
                    color="0x00ff00"
                    horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" selectedIndex="1"

                    <!-- Warning! Better create custom ToggleButtonBar with your logic mouseOver -->
                    mouseOver="{UITextField((event.target).mx_internal::getTextField()).textColor=0xff0000}"
                    >
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <fx:Object label="Home" id="home"  screenIndex="-1"/>
        <fx:Object label="About" id="about"  screenIndex="1"/>
        <fx:Object label="Contact" id="contact" screenIndex="2"/>
        <fx:Object label="Help" id="help" screenIndex="3"/>
    </mx:dataProvider> 
</mx:ToggleButtonBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to element tag:

```
onmouseover="this.style.color='#123456'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#654321'"
```

Replace the first color with what you want to change it to, second one to the color it is normally.

Or add this to your stylesheet:

```
#labelid1:hover {color:#123456;}
#labelid2:hover {color:#123456;}
#labelid3:hover {color:#123456;}
```

Better yet add a class name to each of the buttons and use

```
.labelclassname:hover {color:#123456;}
```

Comment: I have given protected function onmouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
    
    toggBar.setStyle("color",0xffffff);
   }
   
   protected function onmouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
    
    toggBar.setStyle("color",0x000000);
   }
but on mouseover rest of the buttons text color got changed but the one which i rolled over text color didn't get changed.

Comment: Hi irregularexpressions can you please post with example i tried in different ways but whatever i do when i rollover the text color is always black. Thanks for your help